# How to find closest sibling with class that is substring of a class in the selected element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following structure:

```
<li class="header group1"></li>
<li class="group1"></li>
<li class="group1"></li>
<li class="group1bottom"></li>

<li class="header group2"></li>
<li class="group2"></li>
<li class="group2"></li>
<li class="group2bottom"></li>

.. and so on
```

I get the headers:

```
let headers = $('.header');
```

then I need to loop through each of the headers elements, extract the other class containing the `groupx`, and match each of it with it's corresponding `groupxbottom`:

```
headers.each(function() {
   // hide each groupxbottom element
});
```

I've tried a few attempts using `$(this).classList[0]` with regex to extract the specific class but could not get the correct result

Comment: It's a bit hard to give you a 100% good answer without seeing more html structure, but try something like `$('.header.group1').nextAll(".group1bottom:first").hide()`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I updated the question. I could even do something like `.parent(..).find(..)` but the issue is how to extract that `group1` from the selected element? I will need to somehow extract this value by partial search i.e. `group` in this case, then append the extra string at the end then do that matching, but I'm not sure how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$('.header').each(function() {
  var n = $(this).attr("class").match(/group(\d+)/)[1];
  $(`.group${n}bottom`).hide();
})
```

`var n = $(this).attr("class").match(/group(\d+)/)[1];` will extract the number from the corrosponding `groupX` class

**Demo**

```js
$('.header').each(function() {
  var n = $(this).attr("class").match(/group(\d+)/)[1];
  $(`.group${n}bottom`).hide();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="header group1">header</li>
<li class="group1">group1</li>
<li class="group1">group1</li>
<li class="group1bottom">group1bottom</li>

<li class="header group2">header</li>
<li class="group2">group2</li>
<li class="group2">group2</li>
<li class="group2bottom">group2bottom</li>
```

Comment: That is perfect. Out of curiosity, why does  `match(/group(\d+)/)` return 2 results: one the full class name, and second just the number?

Comment: @Stackerito: have a look at the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match); effectively though `match` returns the whole match (the string matched by the regular expression), and the captured match (the part of the string captured by the parentheses).

Comment: @DavidThomas thank you. @Carsten, I'm not sure if it's too late already, but the problem is that I need to match the closest sibling because there might be more than 1 match for `groupxbottom`, using `:first` won't work in this case because it will always match the first one

Answer (score 1):

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('li.header')).forEach(el1 => {
  const arr = (el1.className).split(' ');
  const cl = arr[1] + 'bottom';
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('li.' + cl)).forEach(el2 => {
    el2.style.display = 'none';
  });
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="header group1">header group1</li>
  <li class="group1">group1</li>
  <li class="group1">group1</li>
  <li class="group1bottom">group1bottom</li>

  <li class="header group2">header group2</li>
  <li class="group2">group2</li>
  <li class="group2">group2</li>
  <li class="group2bottom">group2bottom</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there anyway to make it work on the `headers` elements selected by the jQuery selector? Because I'm using it for other things as well

Comment: hum I'm not really jquery! Anyway if you do same logic. 1) you select all li.header 2)for each you make an array of classlist 3) you take the 2nd element of the array 4) you add to this string the string "bottom" 5) you search by class all li with this new formed class 6) you display none